# writing ajax response to div browser hanged

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am getting the large amount of data from the web service and displaying in the jsp using jquery ajax. At that time my browser is hanged up to 5 sec.

Please suggest how can write the data in jsp

My code is like this

```
$.get('search.action?index='+indexval+'&searchKey='+searchkey, 
   function (result) {    
      document.getElementById('searchResult').innerHTML = result;
   });
```

Comment: How are you doing it now, can you provide your jsp code (since that is what you are actually asking about)

Answer (score 1):

You should post the server side script since that's what its seems to taking too much time.

You should also try:

$.get('search.action?index='+indexval+'&searchKey='+searchkey, 
   function (result) {
      $('#searchResult').html(result);
   });

since I think it's more efficient

Comment: I am retrieving the data from service